# Show amount and total from the cart

Tags: php, html, pdo, shopping-cart, cart

I was wondering what will be the best way to show the number of items and the total price for those item which are already in  cart(shopping basket).
The header.php page is on all my pages. so whatever page the user goes to they should be able to still see what the number of item in page and total price.

For an example if I had about 7 items my cart and let's say those item cost about $600.78. How cab I count those item up and show the number and total price in the div below.

**example**

Let's say u go on Nike website and buy 3 pairs of Nike shoes. If u look on top of the page it tells u how many items u have in your basket and the total price for all those items.

**My header.php**

```
<div class="cart">
<div class="shbag">
<a href ="cart.php">
</div>
<ul>         
                    <li class="item"><a>
                    Item
                    <span id="items">0</span>
                    </a></li>
                <li class="cart_price"><a href=""
                title="Cart">
                Total &#163;
                <span id="cart_total">0.00</span></a></li>  


                <!--cart page -->
                <li><a href="cart.php">
                <span class="check_bdr" 
                title="Checkout">View bag</span></a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @saran banerjee can you please take a look at this one

Comment: is it giving some error or are you asking whether how you have represented the cart currently is good way or doing it or not.

Comment: @saranbanerjee I have not idea how to do... That why I asked here. I can't think of any way of doing.

Comment: look into this link : http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/ you will at least get a basic idea of building a shopping cart.

Comment: I know how to build a shopping cart... Basically ny question is. For example if u go on a shopping website and add an item into a basket. On top of the page it tells u how many items u have in your basket and the total price. That is what my question is

Comment: I have edited the question and added some examples to explain what My question is... Hope that helps and can also remember it from HOLD. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach:

header.php

```
<?php require_once('minicart.php'); ?>

<div class="cart">
<div class="shbag">
<a href ="cart.php">
</div>
<ul>         
    <li class="item">
        Item <span id="items"><?php echo cart_item_count() ?></span>
    </li>
    <li class="cart_price">
        <a href="" title="Cart">Total &#163;
            <span id="cart_total"><?php echo cart_total() ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>  
    <!--cart page -->
    <li>
        <a href="cart.php">
            <span class="check_bdr" title="Checkout">View bag</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

minicart.php

```
<?php

function cart_item_count()
{
    return count($_SESSION['cart_array'])
}

function cart_total()
{
    // calculate your cart total here

    return $cart_total;
}
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work :'(

Comment: Could you post your full content of minicart.php? Mine is a incomplete sample.

Comment: i added `$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
$cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;`

Comment: also the way u have approach means that the main `cart.php` is completely separate from `minicart.php`

Comment: Yes, minicart.php is a separated file. It has only 2 functions to return item count and cart total. Your header.php uses those 2 functions to echo.

Comment: In that case I will try this out but will add it in my global.php file with contents my PDO connection and fetchdir etc

Comment: ussing 2 items from your answer I managed to write my own php code to show the answer...